# Using HTML from webserver in Thunderbird email signature

Tags: thunderbird, signature

I want to insert html from a webserver as an email signature, but the UI doesn't allow it directly. I tried creating a local HTML with an iframe that sources the remote content, but thunderbird isn't referencing it.

There is a reasonable chance this is designed for security, but is a little irritating.

Is there any way of achieving this?